# NuGet restore works if old version 0.*, but fails with version 2.*

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I've got a VSTS build, starting from a blank, originally with just Node.js bits, but now adding some C# bits.

Added the NuGet restore, build sln and vstest tasks as part of the update to the build.

Build fails on the NuGet restore task with the error around the MSTest TestAdapter ...

```
Restoring NuGet package MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11.
Restoring NuGet package MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.1.11' of package 'MSTest.TestFramework'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.1.11' of package 'MSTest.TestAdapter'.
Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '1.1.11' of package 'MSTest.TestFramework'.
    Unable to find version '1.1.11' of package 'MSTest.TestAdapter'.
```

Why doesn't it pick up the MSTest package?

*And even more puzzling to me ??? ...*

- I spotted the task was version 2.*
- tried setting it to version 0.* ...
- **and the build works !!** ... runs tests, etc.

Why does version 0.* work, yet the latest version 2.* fails?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, do you check use packages from NuGet.org option for NuGet restore task? Try to set system.debug to true and queue build, then post the detail build log here. You also can try to use higher version of these packages and try again.

Comment: Can you share the package.config file?